# Configuring hosting and deep linking using the same domain - Branch.io

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io, applinks, android-app-links

I have purchased a site on bigrock and also hosted on a server. However I now plan to deeplink my domain using branch.io . Is it possible to host my website and deeplink only the url path using the same root domain.

Comment: For example if Configure www.someapp.com for branch, is it possible to use app.someapp.com for my hosting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible if you are trying to set a custom root domain for your Branch App which you are already using. We always need full control of the domain if you want to use it as a link domain. So to make it work it'll have to be exclusive to Branch Name servers only. Any custom domain that you use as your app link domain can not be used for other purposes.

Comment: Can a subdomain be used for hosting in such cases?

Comment: @Karthik why did you remove your answer to my question here and can you provide some insight into my question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760936/what-stops-malicious-users-from-getting-my-branch-key-in-my-javascript-source-co

Comment: @shreddish looks like the post got deleted by moderator Jean-François Fabre. I am not sure as to why it was deleted. I'll try re-answering it. If that doesn't help I'd suggest you to directly mail us to support@branch.io

Comment: @JDForLife unfortunately any custom domain which you use can not be used for hosting purpose.

Comment: I mean can I use root domain for branch and a subdomain for hosting purposes ?

Comment: @KartikShandilya Is it use root domain for branch and subdomain for hosting.

Comment: can you share some example in your original post?